# av[1] and av[1][0] Not the same address?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-address, argv

What's up ? 
I can't understand this issue... 
I know that the first element of an array stock the address of the entire array. But in this situation i can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    printf("&av[1]= %p\n", &av[1]);
    printf("&av[1][0]= %p\n", &av[1][0]);

    return(0);
}
```

**Input**

```
./a.out "Hello"
```

**Output**

```
&av[1]= 0x7ffee0ffe4f0
&av[1][0]= 0x7ffee0ffe778
```

Comment: `av[1]` and `&av[1][0]` are the same. An array (`av[1]` -- *not really an array, but just go with it for now*) is converted to a pointer to its first element (`&av[1][0]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If somebody told you that `char **av` declares a two-dimensional array, they did you a disservice. In `char **av`, `av` is a pointer to a `char *`, possibly the first `char *` of several. So `av[1]` is a `char *`—it is a **pointer** to a `char`, and `&av[1]` is **the address of that pointer**.

`av[1][0]` is the `char` that `av[1]` points to, and `&av[1][0]` is the address of that `char`.

The pointer to the `char` and the `char` are of course not in the same place, so `&av[1]` and `&av[1][0]` are different.

In contrast, if you had an array, such as `char av[3][4]`, then `av` is an array of 3 arrays of 4 `char`. In that case, `av[1]` is an array of 4 `char`, and `&av[1]` would be the address of (the start of) that array. `&av[1][0]` would be the address of the first `char` in that array. Since the `char` is at the beginning of the array, the address of the array and the address of the `char` are the same.

(However, they are not necessarily represented the same way in a C implementation, and printing them with `%p` can show different results even though they refer to the same place in memory.)

Comment: Woo thanks that help me a lot ! I have a last question maybe stupid... How can you differentiate an array multidimensional and en array of pointer ?

Comment: @EricLing: The type is determined by the declaration of the identifier, except that declarations of function parameters automatically convert arrays to pointers. So `int x[3][4];` declares an array of 3 arrays of 4 `int`, `int *x[3];` declares an array of 3 pointers to `int`, and `int (*x)[4]` declares a pointer to an array of 4 `int`.. In function parameters, `int x[3][4]` declares a pointer to an array of 4 `int`, and `int *x[3]` declares a pointer to a pointer to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`av` isn't a two-dimensional array here. It's an array of pointers.

Whereas with a two dimensional array, `&av[1][0]` would have the same address as `&av[1]`; in an array of pointers , `&av[1][0]` means take the second (index=1) pointer, dereference it, and give me the address of the first element of what the dereferenced pointer target points at (the target of `av[1]` is also a pointer).

`&av[1]` is the address of the second `char*`, `&av[1][0]` is the address of the first character that the second `char*` points at. Different things.

Answer (score 1):

`av` is an array of pointers where each element of this array points to a `char array` (of type `char *`) in which each character you are passing as input to the program is stored.

As you can see by the following variation of your program, `av[0]` stores the address of `av[0][0]` (i.e. points to the first position of the string stored in `av[0][0]`) which contains the character `.` and `av[1]` stores the address of `av[1][0]` (i.e. points to the first position of the string stored in `av[1][0]`)  which contains the character `H`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{

    printf("&av[0]= %p\n", &av[0]);
    printf("&av[1]= %p\n", &av[1]);

    printf("av[0]= %p\n", av[0]);
    printf("av[1]= %p\n", av[1]);

    printf("av[0][0]= %c\n", av[0][0]);
    printf("av[0][1]= %c\n", av[0][1]);


    printf("av[0][0]= %p\n", &av[0][0]);
    printf("av[0][1]= %p\n", &av[0][1]);

    printf("av[1][0]= %c\n", av[1][0]);
    printf("av[1][1]= %c\n", av[1][1]);

    printf("av[1][0]= %p\n", &av[1][0]);
    printf("av[1][1]= %p\n", &av[1][1]);

    return(0);
}
```

which provides the following output:

```
$ ./a.out "Hello"
&av[0]= 0x7fff53625cf8
&av[1]= 0x7fff53625d00

av[0]= 0x7fff53626ee9
av[1]= 0x7fff53626ef1

av[0][0]= .
av[0][1]= /
&av[0][0]= 0x7fff53626ee9
&av[0][1]= 0x7fff53626eea

av[1][0]= H
av[1][1]= e
&av[1][0]= 0x7fff53626ef1
&av[1][1]= 0x7fff53626ef2
```

Graphically it is something like (significant part of addresses were removed for simplification purposes):

```
      av: | 26ee9 | 26ef1 |
              |       |
            av[0]   av[1] 
 address:   25cf8   25d00
```

---

```
   av[0]: |   .  |    /   | ...
              |       |
          av[0][0] av[0][1] 
 address:   26ee9   26eea
```

---

```
   av[1]: |   H  |    e   | ...
              |       |
          av[1][0] av[1][1] 
 address:   26ef1   26ef2
```

I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

`av` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `char`s.  So its second element (the second element of the array) is, indeed a pointer.  `&av[1]` is it's address (the address of a pointer, not the address of a character).

On the other side, `av[1][0]` is the first character of that second string.  Its address is a `char` address, where the first character is stored.

Both addresses are addresses of different things, so it's normal they point to different places.

`av[1]` and `&av[1][0]`  are, respectively, the pointer value (that points to the first char) and the address of the first char of the second string, so **they must be pointers showing the same value**. The same happens to `*av[1]` and `av[1][0]`, they represent the same pointed to character.